# Excel drop down requires information to be pulled out from two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a form within an Excel spreadsheet for a client.

The drop down requires information to be pulled out from two columns on the **lookupDept** workbook and merged. For instance I have:

```
deptCode deptName
BS       Business School
CD       Design and Technology
CG       Chemical Engineering
CM       Chemistry
CO       Computer Science
```

and this needs to appear on the drop down as

```
BS - Business School
CD - Design and Technology
CG - Chemical Engineering
CM - Chemistry
CO - Computer Science
```

This is the code I'm currently using, unfortunately it does not seem to work and returns a **Compile Error: Invalid Next control variable reference**. Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim c_deptCode As Range
Dim c_deptName As Range
Dim ws_dept As Worksheet
Set ws_dept = Worksheets("lookupDept")

For Each c_deptCode In ws_dept.Range("deptCode")
  With Me.cbo_deptCode
    .AddItem c_deptCode.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_deptCode.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End With
Next c_deptCode

For Each c_deptName In ws_dept.Range("deptName")
  With Me.cbo_deptCode
    .AddItem c_deptName.Value
  End With
Next cLoc

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second `For` loop, you are calling `Next cLoc`, but the loop is initialized as `For Each cDeptName`. Try changing the `Next` to `Next cDeptName` to advance the correct variable.